# R3 vector sum, dot, and cross products not passing all tests

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector

My professor assigned us this as homework on Stepik and my code has only passed 50% of the tests. Does anyone know why? I can't see the tests it hasn't passed, so I don't have a clue.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
v1 = input()
v2 = input()
tuple1 = tuple(float(item) for item in v1.split())
tuple2 = tuple(float(item) for item in v2.split())
arr1 = np.array(tuple1)
arr2 = np.array(tuple2) 

#vector sum
s = np.add(arr1, arr2)  
soma = np.round(s,2)
print(*soma)

#dot product
d = np.dot(arr1, arr2)
dot = np.round(d,2)
print(dot)

#cross product 
c = np.cross(arr1, arr2)
cross = np.round(c,2)
print(*cross)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the output of this program, and compared it to the expected output from the assignment?

Comment: Is the program supposed to do anything special if `v1` and/or `v2` is empty?

Comment: what values of `v1` and `v2` make this work ?  what are you expecting ?

Comment: Yes, the question gave us a sample input and output and it worked out as expected. The question also doesn't say anything about v1 or v2 being empty.

Comment: Why does this round the outputs?